# Multiple 'Cookie' headers in a node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, http-headers, request

I've seen how to make a request with a single cookie, and I've seen how to write a response with multiple cookies, but does anyone know how to write a request in node.js using http module (if possible) with multiple 'Cookie' headers?

So far the only ways I've seen to make a request in node.js involve passing an object as the parameter to a function, which would require having two identical keys.

```
headers = {
    Cookie: firstCookie,
    Cookie: secondCookie
}
```

so wouldn't work.

This is a node.js question, but I'm not extremely confident with http, so I'm not sure if there isn't a way to set two distinct cookies in header.  Is it possible to concatenate the two into a single header?  Would a request with two separately defined cookies vary from one with a single header containing both?

Comment: That api is for writing response headers not request headers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'Cookie' property you added is a direct header in your HTTP request. 
You should use only one 'Cookie' header and encode your cookies properly to one valid cookie header string, like that:

```
var headers = {
    Cookie: 'key1=value1; key2=value2'
}
```

Also, instead of using nodeJS native HTTP client which usually will make you write lots of boilerplate code, I would recommend you to use a much simplified library like [Requestify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify)..

This is how you can make an HTTP request with cookies using requestify:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

requestify.get('http://example.com/api/resource', {
    cookies: {
        'key1': 'val1',
        'key2': 'val2',    
    }
})
  .then(function(response) {
      // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
      response.getBody();
  }
);
```

Comment: Requestify sounds like what I'm looking for, but my projects already written with http so I used your first answer instead.  Thanks